# How to compute the left singular eigenvector matrix (U) from the output of prcomp() for PCA in R?

Tags: r, pca, matrix, svd, matrix-decomposition

I am examining the output of the `prcomp()` function in R for PCA in light of the singular value decomposition equation:

$X = U \cdot \Sigma \cdot V^{T}$, where:

$X$: is the standardized original data matrix

$\Sigma$: is the eigenvalues matrix given by the output of `prcomp()` as `$sdev` but squared root

$V$: is the right singular eigenvector matrix (wrongly called loadings) in the output of `prcomp()` as `$rotation`

$U$: is the left singular eigenvector is **NOT** given by the output of `prcomp()`, unlike `svd()` as `$u`, however `prcomp()` provides the raw component scores matrix ($U\cdot \Sigma$) as `$x` which is practically useful for plotting purposes.

Now suppose I want to compute the $U$ matrix from the output of the `prcomp()` function using the `mtcars` built-in dataset.

To achieve this mathematically, both sides of the equation need to be multiplied by $\Sigma^{-1} \cdot V$ this will result in identity matrices for both $V$ and $\Sigma$ on the right side leaving us with:

$U = X \cdot \Sigma^{-1} \cdot {V}$

Note: I used `svd()` function for the sake of validating the results

**My trial in R**

```
# the svd() method
A <- as.matrix(mtcars[,c(1:7,10,11)], row = 9, byrow = T)
S <- scale(A)
svd.pca <- svd(S)
svd.pca$u # left singular eigenvector matrix U

# the prcomp() method
prcomp.pca <- prcomp(A, center = TRUE,scale. = TRUE)

# to get inverse of a matrix in R we use the solve() function
diag(prcomp.pca$sdev) %*% (solve(diag(prcomp.pca$sdev))) # identity matrix for Sigma
prcomp.pca$rotation %*% t(prcomp.pca$rotation) # identity matrix for V

# now compute the U matrix from prcomp() output per the equation above for U
prcomp.pca$u <- S %*% (solve(diag(prcomp.pca$sdev))) %*% t(prcomp.pca$rotation)
prcomp.pca$u

round(svd.pca$u, 3) == round(prcomp.pca$u, 3) # FALSE, what am I missing?
```

So the computed $U$ matrix eventually didn't match the $U$ matrix of the `svd()` function, what am I missing here to obtain the $U$ matrix from the output of `prcomp()`?

Comment: Why not just inspect the source?  The code is in `stats::prcomp.default` and is only a few dozen lines long.  Note that without details of how the algorithm works, you cannot expect to recover $U$ exactly because it is not uniquely defined: in particular, any of its columns may be arbitrarily negated.

Comment: @whuber, you mean `stats:::prcomp.default` 3 semicolons instead of 2. I am inspecting it right now.

Comment: @whuber, so from source code the difference was in the sigma part, now U matrix could be recovered. Thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved by computing the $\Sigma$ first from the `prcomp()` function to make it numerically equivalent to that of the `svd()`and it turned out after inspecting the source code of `prcomp()` this can be achieved by the following:

```
sigma <- prcomp.pca$sdev * sqrt(max(1, nrow(S) - 1))
round(sigma, 2) == round(svd.pca$d, 2) # TRUE 

diag(sigma) %*% solve(diag(sigma)) # identity matrix of Sigma
prcomp.pca$rotation %*% t(prcomp.pca$rotation) # identity matrix of V

prcomp.pca$u <- S %*% prcomp.pca$rotation %*% solve(diag(sigma))
round(svd.pca$u, 3) == round(prcomp.pca$u, 3) # TRUE
```